# Danish characters are replaced in CSV

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding

My code to create a CSV file that contains Danish characters

```
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
     Response.ContentType = "application/csv;charset=utf-8";
     Response.Charset = "utf-8";
     Response.Write(sb.ToString());
     Response.End();
```

Don't know why but when result CSV is created danish characters are replaced with some special characters like `??j`.Can any one give me any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the source text in the StringBuilder UTF-8? If not there is a chance that .NET gets confused and writes the wrong characters. If it isn't in UTF-8 try running [Encoding.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx) before writing to the client.